# Flutter : How to update widget state from background / service?

Tags: flutter-provider, flutter-widget, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm new in flutter.

I created an service with the android alarm manager plugin to get data from json Api every x minutes. That's ok.

I use a stateful widget with streambuilder + futurebuilder to fetch my json data. At the first load, data are displayed, but when i put new data in the stream (sink.add) from the background / service, the widget is never reloaded.

Please How can reload a widget from the background / service ?

I read more & more tuto and i don't find the anwser.

Many thanks

Comment: I don't know why software developers keep basic necessities hidden like deep secrets. I just want to know how to display a data updated from a background service.
I'm 85% sure we should use Bloc pattern for this.